# What is the exact name of auto-restore page position feature in stackoverflow sites

Tags: discussion

In stackoverflow sites, if we hit the refresh button. It will automatically scrolls to the exact position where we were while hitting the refresh. I would like to know what is the name of this feature/technique.

We normally achieve this by appending #ref "ahref" to the url.

Using what technology it is implemented. Is it anything I can do with plain HTML?

Comment: Don't most sites do this be default on refresh? Although I'm sure some don't.

Comment: It's a browser feature. Also what's the random "html5" tag for?

Comment: How does this belong on meta? It's asking about HTML technologies and not about how SO works. SO was just given as an example...

Comment: @Matti Very recently, I noticed. So, I thought this could be one of HTML5's feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works on all websites, or at least just about all. I don't think this is a particular feature, the browser just does this to give you a better experience.

If this is not working on a site, you might want to check if there is anything still loading. Browsers usually wait until the entire page loads before scrolling you to where you were, and if you have a script or something else blocking the page from finishing loading, you might not be jumped back.

Comment: Oops! I didn't noticed this on other sites until reading this. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian said this is a feature of most browsers. However, you might experience problems when doing a post-back in ASP.NET.  There used to be a feature called *[Smart Navigation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913721/en-us)* to keep the scroll position. Maybe this is what you had in mind?